# Suppressing value output in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

````
  ```{r, messages=FALSE, warnings=FALSE}
which(is.na(Company$Item.26))
  ```
````

When I go through the chunk the output still goes through.

which returns some values :

```
[1] 20 21
```

The invisible function works but I don't want to see that in the final product. How can I suppress this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `include=FALSE` to have the chunk evaluated, but not display code or results.

Use `results='hide'` to have code displayed, but not output.

Try [this useful tutorial](http://kbroman.org/knitr_knutshell/pages/Rmarkdown.html).